# Not displaying errors in php

Tags: php

I am debugging some errors in my `PHP` bus booking site. My issue is that I am not able to display errors. When I googled this issue it shows you can achieve it though `php.ini`. But unfortunately I haven't find any `php.ini` file .

Now the error is showing as

> This page isn’t working
>
> cableandmedia.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP
>   ERROR 500

Comment: On your page  you can do it like :- `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);`

Comment: should I add this code on each and every php page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your all-pages/or-a-common-file which-is-included-in-each-file.

On top just after starting `<?php` add these two lines:-

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

***If you have `php.ini` file then check these two variables:-***

```
display_errors
error_reporting
```

Now change these variables values to:-

```
display_errors=ON
error_reporting=E_ALL
```

Now save the file and ***restart your server(important if you are working on localhost)***.And you have good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your php file. To debug

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: i havent a `php.ini` file.  should i create a phi.ini file and just add this 2 lines of code

Comment: You need to add this line to your `php` file. Not in `ini` file